# ¿COMO COMPLETAR INPUTS DEPENDIENDO DE UN SELECT DE LA BASE DE DATOS?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

necesito ayuda con un programa, tengo una tabla "Ventas" donde al agregar información debo seleccionar un cliente (ya añadido antes), lo tengo que seleccionar de un "SELECT", el cual fue llenado de la tabla "Cliente". Lo que necesito es que al momento de elegir uno por su id, me muestre en los input el nombre y teléfono de cada uno de ellos, dependiendo el que se seleccionó, dicha información debe provenir de la base de datos (tabla "Cliente"). Estuve buscando ayuda en algunos foros y no lo hacen con base de datos. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?. Me sería de mucha ayuda sus respuestas. Estoy utilizando laravel 8 para backend y para las vistas las plantillas de blade.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <h1>Número de cliente</h1>
  <select name="" id="">
     <option disabled>-- Escoge un numero --</option>
     @foreach ($clientes as $cliente)
     <option {{old('id') == $cliente->id? 'selected' : ''}} value="{{ $cliente->id}}" }}>
        {{$cliente->id}}
     </option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <h1>Nombre</h1>
  <input type="text" id="nombre">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <h1>Teléfono</h1>
  <input type="text" id="telefono">
</div>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!"no lo hacen con base de datos" y si no lo hacen asi, de donde sacan toda la informacion que necesitan? o querras decir que ya la tienen? probaste algo?

Comment: Gracias, si, al decir que no lo hacen con base de datos me refiero a que por ejemplo seleccionan un nombre, en ese input su "value" es igual a su id. Entonces al momento de que aparezca el id en el otro input, muestra el valor de esa option.

Comment: aja.. y entonces, cual es el problema??? usa como value el nombre...

Comment: No puedo hacerlo porque necesito otros datos aparte del nombre. Y tienen que venir de la tabla de Clientes.

Comment: y entonces, vas a tener que ir a buscarlos a la base de datos.. sigo sin entender tu pregunta.. queres traer datos de la base de datos, sin ir a la base de datos?

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es.. no se como hacer, para que luego de seleccionar un item, vaya a mi backend y busque los otros datos para completar mi pantalla.. puede ser esa tu duda? si es esa tu duda, entonces aclara en que lenguaje esta tu front, en que lenguaje esta tu back, como te conectas a tu back... y si intentaste algo....

Comment: Si, así es, estoy trabajando todo en Laravel 8.

Comment: bueno, yo no tengo ni idea de laravel (ni php), con lo cual, yo usaria el boton [edit], reescribiria la pregunta con el problema real que tenes, y pondria los detalles del codigo del front y back.. y sacaria las etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver aca (javascript, bootstrap, html, mysql... todas esas, no tienen nada que ver con tu problema)

Comment: de paso, aprovecha y lee los enlaces que te pase...

Comment: Si, gracias. Por sus consejos.

Comment: hola encontraste solucion para tu pregunta estoy en la misma situacion